# Is there a main question about appstream-cli hanging bug that we should dupe link to?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

There are a lot of different questions around the bug with appstream-cli interfering with `apt-get update` commands, with much varying titles.

Some examples: 
https://askubuntu.com/q/775108/320386 
[appstreamcli hanging with 100% CPU usage during update](https://askubuntu.com/q/774986) 
[apt-get is stuck at "Fetched XXKb in XXsec"](https://askubuntu.com/q/774918) 
[Ubuntu 16 apt get update very slow / not working](https://askubuntu.com/q/775076/320386)
https://askubuntu.com/q/775027/320386
[Apt-get update hangs in 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/774985)

Should these all be marked as dupes, and is there a suitable question to link them all to?

Comment: "apt-get is stuck at “Fetched XXKb in XXsec” seems to be the best answer based on activity since you asked, I would pick that one too.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this question...

[appstreamcli hanging with 100% CPU usage during update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774986/appstreamcli-hanging-with-100-cpu-usage-during-update)

...is the end of a stream of duplicates. A lot of those questions were considered duplicates of another question, which were duplicates of another...it led to this question.

This question is also protected by the community, has high votes, and high views, so I would link to it.

Answer (score -4):

> Is there a main question about appstream-cli ***bug*** that we should dupe link to?

These questions if are indeed bugs should be closed. CLOSE THEM! That's what our scope is. If we close and delete those, the information from the bug tracker will rank better and people can find the solution.

BTW, a fix was released, so this kind of question is transitory by nature. It wouldn't help anyone with the same issue a year from now, not even a month. That's more reason to close them.

Comment: While it is a bug, there is a workaround that was provided. If we closed all the questions (albeit, they are bugs), many people would be lost and looking for the work around. This site is much nicer, easier to read, and more direct than trying to find the workaround from the bug reports.

Comment: @Zzzach... What? They would see the bug report along with all the workarounds, in fact the "workaround" for this bug was available *before* the question was asked, check the time stamps.

Comment: You do have a point, now that I see. I didn't realize before that closing the question as a bug report would still make it searchable (right?, maybe I'm wrong here).

Comment: @Zzzach... I'm not sure what you are agreeing with me? I'm saying that now AU ranks higher for bug reports instead of Launchpad, the Ubuntu bug tracker. That is wrong.